# What is the use of function void QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(bool useAlpha)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In Qt 5.1.0 documentation it says

> void QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(bool useAlpha)
>
> useAlpha specifies whether to use alpha transparency on newly created windows.
>
> In any application which expects to create translucent windows, it's necessary to set this to
> true before creating the first QQuickWindow, because all windows will share the same
> QOpenGLContext. The default value is false.

I have used this function to create a transparent background with a QQuickView, However it didn't change anything (on Windows 7) as far as I can see, here is my code:

```
QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
QQuickView view;

view.setColor(Qt::transparent);
view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.qml");
view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

bool b = view.hasDefaultAlphaBuffer();

QWidget* p = QWidget::createWindowContainer(&view, NULL, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
p->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
p->show();
```

and here is my test.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle
{
 width: 300;
 height: 300;
 color: "transparent"

 Rectangle
 {
  x: 50;
  y: 50;
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
  color: "blue";
 }
}
```

So what is the use of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use the function on your QQuickView object:

```
view.setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
```